# only one value is get use of explode variable in get method

Tags: laravel

i have use explode variable to get the value using get method but that return only one value

```
    $part_id=explode(",",$request->input('part_id'));


   $get_ltr = part::where('status',1)->where('part_no',$part_id)->get();


    foreach($get_ltr as $key =>$value)
    {

        $ltr[$key] = $value['ltr'];

    }
```

that gives me only one record what is issue in my code please help me

Comment: What does the request (query string) look like? Try `dd($request->input('color_id'))`

Comment: which one return only one value on explode

Comment: $get_ltr that gives me only one value

Comment: i have given issue in part_id that look like Collection {#487 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▶]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you should use `whereIn()`.

```
$ids = explode(',', $request->input('part_id'));

$get_ltr = part::where('status',1)->whereIn('part_no', $ids)->get();

foreach($get_ltr as $key =>$value){
    $ltr[$key] = $value['ltr'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
$color_id=explode(",",$request->input('color_id'));
    $part_id=explode(",",$request->input('part_id'));
    $qty=explode(",",$request->input('qty'));


    $qty_ltr = [30,15];


   $get_ltr = part::where('status',1)->whereIn('part_no',$part_id)->get();


    foreach($get_ltr as $key =>$value)
    {

        $ltr[$key] = $value['ltr'];

    }
```